# NSDate / NSDateFormatter returning GMT on iPhone iOS 4.3

Tags: iphone, nsdate

Why would this code be giving me GMT? (I am in US Mountain Time)

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init]  autorelease];
[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterLongStyle];
[dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterLongStyle];
[dateFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];     

NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
NSString *storeTime = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:now];
```

Comment: Can you write the complete date you are getting?

Comment: Try `[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]]`

Comment: Well, it is exactly 6 hours in the future, so GMT instead of my local mountain time. For example, at 9:30pm last night I was getting

Comment: I tried     [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];
But I get the same result -- GMT not mountain time.

Comment: Wow this was actually a bug in Numbers! Numbers upon import was changing my string August 26, 2011 2:20:05 PM MDT to Aug 26, 2011 8:20 PM. So somehow it decided to show me the date in GMT! So this was not an NSDateFormatter bug. Thanks to those who answered.

Answer (score 3):

An `NSDate` represents a concrete point in time, *regardless of the timezone*.  Put another way, an `NSDate` does not have a timezone.  Timezones are only relevant when you want to display the date to the user.  So 9:30pm in Mountain Time **is** 3:30am (+1 day) in GMT (assuming a 6 hour time difference).

`NSDate`, since it does not have a timezone, must pick one when producing a human-readable version to return as its `-description`.  To make things simple, *it always returns a date formatted in the GMT time zone*.  If you would like the date formatted to be in a different timezone, you can set the `-timezone` property of an `NSDateFormatter`, and then convert the date into a string using the `-stringFromDate:` method.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, turns out this was a bug in Apple's Numbers on the Mac. Numbers was not interpreting the date string, or rather it was adding the time offset. The NSDate string, after formatting, was correct all along.