# Why is an NSString date value being converted to GMT by NSDateFormatter?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsdate, nsdateformatter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [NSDate / NSDateFormatter returning GMT on iPhone iOS 4.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7199807/nsdate-nsdateformatter-returning-gmt-on-iphone-ios-4-3)

When the following code is executed

```
NSString *inputDateString=@"2012-10-19 19:37:54";
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate *test=[formatter dateFromString:inputDateString];
```

the value of "test" is 2012-10-19 23:37:54 +0000 rather than a date value equivalent to the inputDateString. Why is the date being converted to GMT?

EDIT: How do I take an input string date and and convert it to an equivalent NSDate object?

Comment: This has so many duplicates...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=NSDate+GMT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSDate` doesn't store timezones, nor does it care about them. `NSDate` only stores the time that has passed since a given reference date (january 1st 2001). When you use your `NSDateFormatter` like this, it will assume that the timezone of the date matches the users current timezone when converting the string to the date object, however, when you use `NSLog` to check the date, it doesn't have any timezone information. Keep in mind though, that the date is still correct and equal to the input value.

Comment: I understand NSDate is an offset from the reference date. Are you saying the stored value in the "test" variable is actually equal to the inputDateString? It doesn't appear to be because when I do date calculations with the test variable it seems to contain the GMT date. How do I take an input date string and convert it to an equivalent date?

Comment: @ChrisP It is the same date, the representation however is different! If you would pump the date through the `NSDateFormatter` again, it will output the same string that you put into it. Not because the `NSDate` knows or cares about the timezone, but because the `NSDateFormatter` knows about the users timezone and takes care of it. However, both dates reference the exact same point in time.